# incron tab won't fire

Tags: permissions, cron, process, automation

I'm trying to get incrontab running, but it won't work. This is the error I get:

```
access denied on ~/propt/apo/feeds - events will be discarded silently
```

and this is the line in incrontab I want to run:

```
~/propt/apo/feeds IN_ALL_EVENTS php ~/propt/feeds/src/MWS/Send/Send.php -f apo.germany.feeds.php
```

I have also tried

```
~/propt/apo/feeds IN_ALL_EVENTS ~/propt/feeds/src/MWS/Send/Send.php -f apo.germany.feeds.php php
```

but with no success as well.

I altered incrontab as root and I think it should run the processes as root therefor, but after I've seen the errormessage I tried to change permission to the folder with

```
chmod 777 -R ~/propt/apo/feeds
```

but the error message remains the same.

Someone an idea how I can get this running?